# What is the syntax or way of opening a file handle in bash to avoid multiple open/close handles

Tags: linux, bash

I want to open/create a file in a loop and write many lines in it.

Basically I would do it like this:

```bash
for i in {1..100}; do
  echo "line $i">>test.log
done
```

My understanding is that the OS will then open/close the `test.log` file `i` times.

I came accross another syntax/way of doing this:

```bash
exec {log}>>test.log
for i in {1..1000}; do
  echo "line $i" >& $log
done
{log}>&-
```

I assume `exec {log}>>test.log` will open/create the file and keeps it open, wile the `echo "line $i" >& $log`  uses that already opened file?
`{log}>&-` this will close the file handle?

what is this method called and where can I find more information about use cases?

Comment: it's probably worth noting that whatever you're doing in your for loop will probably be much heavier than opening and closing a file; so unless this happens over an uncached network file system with high latency, do not prematurely optimize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, since the fd is only used within a single loop, it's also possible to put the redirection on the loop, without needing to manually close it afterwards:

```
for i in {1..100}; do
    echo "line $i"
done >>test.log
```

Here, you could also use a truncating redirection `> test.log` instead of the appending one with `>>`, if you wanted to clear the file at the start of the loop. It would not be truncated between the loop iterations, since it's the same file handle for the whole loop.

I'm not sure if using `exec` to handle redirections has a particular name, it's just a way to modify redirections that apply for the whole shell. It is a bit odd in that the other use of `exec` would be with a command, where it would replace the whole shell, but here, the shell keeps running.

The one with `{var}>filename` is a non-standard extension, it's [described in Bash's manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html):

> Each redirection that may be preceded by a file descriptor number may instead be preceded by a word of the form {*varname*}. In this case, for each redirection operator except >&- and <&-, the shell will allocate a file descriptor greater than 10 and assign it to {*varname*}. If >&- or <&- is preceded by {*varname*}, the value of varname defines the file descriptor to close. If {*varname*} is supplied, the redirection persists beyond the scope of the command, allowing the shell programmer to manage the file descriptor’s lifetime manually.

It's supported by at least ksh and zsh too (and probably borrowed to Bash from one of those).

Note that you don't need the automatic allocation, but can use a fixed number instead, e.g.:

```
exec 9>>test.log
for i in {1..100}; do
    echo "line $i" >&9
done
exec 9>&-
```

You'll just need to keep track of the fd numbers yourself. Numbers from 3 to 9 should be free to use for the script author; 0, 1 and 2 are the standard file descriptors, and 10 and above may be used by the shells internally.

Answer (score 2):

In the use case that you show, you could just redirect the standard output of the `for` compound command.  This gets rid of the need for juggling file-descriptors.

```bash
for i in {1..100}; do
    printf 'line %d\n' "$i"
done >test.log
```

This creates or truncates the file called `test.log`, and all output to the standard output stream within the loop, unless explicitly redirected elsewhere, will go to that file.   Use `>>` to append to the file instead of truncating it.  The file would be opened once only.

You can do the same with any other compond command:

```bash
if [ -e file ]; then
    echo 'file exists'
else
    echo 'file does not exist'
fi >out.log
```

```bash
{
   echo 'line 1'
   cat some-file
   echo 'last line'
} >lines.txt
```

Comment: Ah nice, I did not know this is possible!